# Python Intellisense suddenly broke; refreshing doesn't fix it

Tags: python, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, intellisense

For some reason, Visual Studio 2015's Python Intellisense completely broke in my project.
Even something as simple as `import sys; sys.` doesn't pop up the members of `sys`.

Sometimes it freezes or even crashes the IDE completely, making it run out of memory or otherwise behaving strangely. I even tried clearing the database and refreshing it, but nothing helped.

What might be causing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that I had added new Search Paths to my project that were inside installed Python libraries. 
(In my case, the library in question was SymPy.)

For whatever reason, Visual Studio's Intellisense chokes when you do this.

Removing these paths and then closing and re-opening the solution fixed the issue.